# When/where are local arrays allocated?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, memory

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation-and-C.html describes *automatic allocation* of local variables. I understand that local variables are commonly allocated on the stack. I can imagine how an `int` might be allocated on the stack; just push its value. But how might an array be allocated?

For example, if you declare an array `char str[10];`, does that 10 bytes of space go on the stack, or is it allocated somewhere else, and only the `str` pointer is pushed to the stack? If the latter, where is the 10 bytes of space allocated?

Furthermore, when exactly are local variables, including arrays, allocated? I commonly see heap allocation referred to as "dynamic allocation", implying that automatic variables are *not* dynamically allocated. But automatic variables may be declared within flow-of-control constructs and function bodies, so the compiler can't possibly know before runtime exactly how much space will be occupied by automatic variables. So automatic variables must also be dynamically allocated, right?

**Edit:** I would like to emphasize the first half of this question. I am most interested in understanding when and where the space for local arrays is allocated. On the stack? Somewhere else?

**Edit 2:** I made a mistake when I originally included the C++ tag for this question. I meant to ask only about the **C** language and its implementations. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: 1) "_But automatic variables may be declared within flow-of-control constructs and function bodies, so the compiler can't possibly know before runtime exactly how much space will be occupied by automatic variables_" You already said the answer to that yourself: "_just push its value_". 2) "_does that 10 bytes of space go on the stack, or is it allocated somewhere else_" You just push `10` `char`s, instead of `1`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but that happens at runtime, so it's also a form of dynamic allocation, correct?

Comment: To understand this, you'll need to have a basic understanding of assembly language and processor architecture. But the answer (in the most common case) is that the stack pointer is adjusted to leave room on the stack for all of the local variables.

Comment: the stack is just the most popular implementation but nothing in the standard says that some other mechanism shouldn't be used.

Comment: @user3386109 I do have a basic understanding of those topics. I would like to know how this works at the level of assembly language. I am most interested in understanding where exactly arrays are allocated. On the stack? Somewhere else?

Comment: Then all you need to do is compile a simple program with the `-S` option and look at the assembly code. Or use the debugger to look at the assembly code. But yes, arrays are on the stack normally. (There are some oddball implementations that don't have a stack, but you shouldn't worry about those right now.)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So you're saying that the physical space for arrays is indeed allocated on the stack, correct?

Comment: @jth "_but that happens at runtime, so it's also a form of dynamic allocation, correct?_" What happens in runtime? All scopes are known at compile time. One can just push the objects to stack at the point of variable declaration, and pop them upon leaving the scope. Array sizes (in C++, at least) must be known at compile time also.

Comment: Keep in mind that because arrays *are* allocated on the stack, and because stack space is limited, it's not a good idea to declare large arrays as local variables.

Comment: @user3386109 I have looked at the assembly output from GCC a bit, but I guess I thought there might be a straightforward, "official" answer to this question. So, just to clarify, you're saying that the physical space for arrays normally goes on the stack? So a 10-byte array occupies 10 bytes of space on the stack?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OK, I guess I was just saying that because the pushes and pops happen at runtime, it seems that this is a form of "dynamic allocation". Unless you're saying that because the stack is already allocated before runtime, it's not true dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes, the array occupies at least 10 bytes of space on the stack. Due to alignment restrictions on some processors, there may be additional wasted space. And no there is no "official" answer, each compiler is free to do what it pleases with regards to how it implements local variables. And there's no requirement to even have a stack.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. The behavior may differ.

Comment: Because of the [As-If rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule), the compiler can do whatever it wants so long as you can't tell the difference. Allocate all up front, allocate as needed, use stack, or use pixie dust, it's all game if the observable behaviour is unchanged.

Comment: "because the pushes and pops happen at runtime" ?  I was wondering what you think the code would do for  "pops"?   To return from a function call, all that appears to happen is that a) the 'stack-ptr'  is restored to the value prior to the call, and the 'pc' is set to the code statement after the call.  For performance, I think 'pops' would do nothing, and there is only the restore of 'stack-ptr'.

Comment: @2785528 Right, I get that. I guess deallocation isn't really my main concern anyway.

Comment: compile time and run time are two totally different events.  During compile time, the compiler calculates the total amount of stack needed to hold the 'automatic' variables, and compiles into the 'header' of the function a statement to modify the stack pointer to allow room for those variables.  At run time, the code is executed to actually adjust the stack pointer to allow for automatic variables

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius,  in C, there is the feature: `Variable Length Array` So the size of an array is not fixed at compile time.  The usual method for a variable length array is to allocate more stack when the actual size of the array is known.  It is all removed from the stack, when the function exits (in a x86 type CPU) via setting the Stack Pointer from the saved Block Pointer

Comment: regarding: *so the compiler can't possibly know before runtime exactly how much space will be occupied by automatic variables*  actually the compiler knows exactly how much space with be needed.  The only 'trick' to that is with VLAs and even then it is simply an adjustment of the Stack Pointer

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for addressing "VLAs" (I hadn't heard that term before). I was also wondering about how those work (because GCC allows using an arbitrary expression for array size). So the space is just added to the end of the stack when it is calculated at runtime?

Comment: @user3629249 When I said "so the compiler can't possibly know before runtime exactly how much space will be occupied by automatic variables", I was mostly thinking that the compiler doesn't know how many times each function will be called, so it doesn't know how much stack space will actually be *used* at runtime. That's why I was questioning why only heap allocation is called "dynamic allocation". Does that make sense? Edit: which is why the compiler can't prevent stack overflow.

Comment: at the entry to each function, the stack pointer is adjusted to allow room for the automatic variables for that function.  When that function exits, the stack pointer is adjusted to where it was pointing before the function was called

Comment: @user3629249 Right, I do understand that now. But I was wondering why we don't call that "dynamic allocation", like we do with heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

In the C 2018 standard, clause 6.2.4, paragraphs 6 and 7 tell us about the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration. Paragraph 6 covers such objects that are not variable length arrays:

> … its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end, execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time.

Thus, if we have this code:

```
{
    PointA;
    int x = 3;
    PointB;
}
```

then `x` exists in the C model as soon as execution reaches `PointA`—its block was entered, and that is when the lifetime of `x` begins. However, although `x` already exists at `PointA`, its value is indeterminate. The initialization only occurs when the definition is reached.

Paragraph 7 tells us about variable length arrays:

> … its lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope of the declaration.

So, if we have this code:

```
{
    PointA;
    int x[n]; // n is some variable.
    PointB;
}
```

then `x` does not exist at `PointA`. Its lifetime begins when `int x[n];` is reached.

Keep in mind this existence is only in terms of C’s abstract model of computing. Compilers are allowed to optimize code as long as the observable results (such as output of the program) are the same. So the actual code generated by a compiler might not create `x` when the block is entered. (It might not create `x` at all; it could be optimized away completely.)

Comment: So, why does the C standard specify that automatic variables (other than VLAs) are created upon entering the block with which they're associated? It seems that the programmer would not be able to tell if they were instead created at their declarations (like VLAs). Shouldn't that be left as an implementation detail?

Comment: @jth: The C standard generally describes computation inside an abstract machine. Separately, it says a C implementation may implement the behaviors in any way it wants as long as the *observed behaviors* are the same. The purpose of writing it this way is to avoid having to write “An automatic object is created when a block is entered, or when the function is entered, or when you need to create it to make it look like it was created when the block was entered…” It is easier just to specify one clear, hopefully simple, implementation and then say “anything that gets the same results is fine.”

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is depends on the language implementation (the compiler). To answer your question, this is (a simplified overview of) what compilers usually do for compiled languages (like C/C++):

When the compiler finishes parsing a function, it keeps a symbol table of all local variables declared in this function, even those declared "syntactically" during the instruction flow of the function (like local loops variables). Later, when it needs to generate the final (assembly) code, it generates the necessary instructions to push (or just moves the stack pointer) a sufficient space for all local variables. So, local loop variables, for instance, are not allocated when the loop starts execution. Rather, they are allocated at the beginning of the execution of the function containing the loop. The compiler also adds instructions to remove this allocated stack space before returning from the function.

So, automatic variables, like your char array, is totally allocated on the stack in this (common) scenario.

[EDIT] Variable length arrays (before C99)

The discussion above was for arrays having lengths known at compile time like this:

```
void f () {
    char n[10];
    ....
}
```

If we stay in C language terms (before C99), variable-length arrays (arrays whose lengths are not known at compile-time, but rather at runtime) are declared as a pointer like this:

```
void f() {
    char *n;
    ... //array is later allocated using some kind of memory allocation construct
}
```

This, in fact, just declares a pointer to the array. Pointers size is known to the compiler. So, as I said above, the compiler will be able to reserve the necessary storage for the pointer on the stack (just the pointer, not the real array) regardless of what will be the size of the array at runtime. When the execution reaches the line that allocates the array (using malloc, for instance), the array storage is **dynamically** allocated on the heap, and its address is stored in the local automatic variable `n`. In languages without garbage collection, this requires freeing (deallocating) the reserved storage from the heap manually (i.e. the programmer should add an instruction to do it in the program when the array is no longer needed). This is not necessary for constant-sized array (that are allocated on the stack) because the compiler removes the stack frame before returning from the function, as I said earlier.

[EDIT2]

C99 variable length arrays cannot be declared on the stack. The compiler must add some code to the resulting machine code that handles its dynamic creation and destruction at runtime.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. But array size is not necessarily known at compile time. For example, GCC allows declaring an array whose size is a randomly generated number. However, I would imagine this space can just be reserved on top of the stack as needed, correct?

Comment: This is incorrect for at least three reasons. One, an implementation might choose to allocate storage for local fixed-size objects when a function is entered or it might do it when each block is entered. Two, for variable length arrays, the size is generally not known until the definition is reached, so storage cannot be allocated until then. Three, it describes storage allocation in terms of implementation, rather than in terms of C semantics. But if we are discussing actual implementation, we must allow for other possibilities, such as there being no allocation at all due to optimization.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I purposely started by this statement "this is (a simplified overview of) what compilers usually do for compiled languages (like C/C++)" to avoid comments like yours. One, an implementation might, indeed, do what you said, but might not, also. They usually do what you said for interpreted languages, but usually do what I said in purely compiled languages (no runtime environment) like C. Two, your argument regarding variable length arrays shows that you don't even understand how it works. See my edit if you would like to understand it.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi: First, “simplified” and “wrong” are different things. One can simplify explanations without making false statements. Second, your added statements about variable length arrays are incorrect. “Variable length array” is a specific term in the C standard that refers to arrays defined with a size that is not a integer constant expression (C 2018 6.7.6.2 4). It does not refer to a pointer to an array or a pointer of any kind. The code `void f() { char n[]; … }` will not compile. The `char n[]` syntax may be used in parameter declarations. It may not be used in that position.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Third, you are right, compilers may decide not to allocate a variable at all due to some optimization technique. It may also decide to allocate all arrays, even constant length ones, dynamically, just like what I explained in my edit (and necessarily deallocate them automatically before the function returns). But, again, "this is (a simplified overview of) what compilers usually do for compiled languages (like C/C++)", not an exhaustive answer. I wanted to make it simple.

Comment: An example of a variable length array is `int x[n]`, where `n` is some expression that is not an integer constant expression. These objects are explicitly treated differently in the C standard; when their lifetimes begin differs from other objects.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right about the syntax of `char n[]`. I corrected my answer.

Comment: `char *n;` does not declare a variable length array. “Variable length array” does not mean an array that is allocated dynamically, as by `malloc`. It is a specific term in the C standard for an array that is defined in code the same way a regular array is except that its size is not an integer constant expression. The size is evaluated during program execution, and the array is created when program control reaches the definition. It is an object of automatic storage duration, the same as a regular array defined at the same place.

Comment: The statement “variable-length arrays are declared as a pointer…” is false. “Variable length array” is a specific term in the C standard for an array whose size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression. It does not refer to arrays that are allocated.

Comment: "*C99 variable length arrays cannot be declared on the stack.*" is incorrect. First off, declarations are a feature of the C language (what the programmer writes) and the stack is an implementation detail. You never declare anything "on the stack". Second, VLAs (as commonly implemented) do store their contents on the stack. See also `alloca()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edits continue to make the answer worse. Variable length arrays are typically implemented using stack, and the compiler does not have to add code that uses dynamic (meaning `malloc` and family) creation and destruction. If you compile `extern void bar(int *); void foo(int n) { int x[n]; bar(x); }` to assembly with a typical compiler, you will see in the generated assembly code that the compiler multiplies `n` by the size of an `int` and subtracts that amount from the stack pointer. It does not call `malloc` or a similar routine.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if you declare an array char str[10];, does that 10 bytes of space go on the stack, or is it allocated somewhere else, and only the str pointer is pushed to the stack? If the latter, where is the 10 bytes of space allocated?

In general, the array's storage is allocated on the stack, just like any other local variable.  This is compiler and target-specific.  Even on a x86_64 machine, a 4 billion byte array is probably not allocated on the stack.  I'd expect one of:  a compile error, a link error, a runtime error, or it works somehow.  In the last alternative, it might call `new[]` or `malloc()` and leave the pointer to the array on the stack in place of the array.

Notice that the array's allocation and its pointer are the same thing, so your addition of ***allocated somewhere else, and only the str pointer*** wording might indicate confusion.  The allocation occurs and the name for it are not independent data.

Comment: Well, the array variable is just a pointer to the first element of the array. So I was wondering if both the pointer and the physical array are stored on the stack, or if, for example, the array is allocated somewhere else (such as a separate stack, or the heap) while the pointer is stored as a local variable on the call stack. But comments seem to indicate that normally both the array and its pointer are stored on the call stack (but also that it is totally implementation-dependent).